# Zend Frame Work Cron Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, zend-framework2

My second cron action (sendDailyRecap) works however I also get an email informing me of an error.

**Error Message:**

```
Zend Framework 2.3.3 application
Usage:

Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided
```

I believe the issue lies in my module.config file.  Any ideas why I'm getting an error (when the job executes correctly)?  I would like to fix this so I no longer get the error email.  Thanks

**module.config**

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Cron\Controller\CronController' => 'Cron\Controller\CronController',
        ),
    ),
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'cronroute' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => 'sendTest',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\CronController',
                            'action' => 'index'
                        ),
                        'route'    => 'sendDailyRecap',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\CronController',
                            'action' => 'sendDailyRecap'
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**Cron Command**

```
/usr/bin/php-cli /home/financialfriend/public_html/public/index.php sendDailyRecap

/usr/bin/php-cli /home/financialfriend/public_html/public/index.php sendTest
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command you are calling to run the cron job, since it's that command which is not matching your routes.

Comment: Thank you Tim.  I used the same command you helped me with last time.  I simply changed the action name to the new action in the controller.

Comment: @TimFountain it actually looks like the error was on my first cron job (sendTest).  This one was working before I added the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to step back one more level.

```
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'sendReminder' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'sendReminder',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\CronController',
                        'action' => 'sendReminder'
                        ),
                )
            ),
            'sendRecap' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'sendDailyRecap',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\CronController',
                        'action' => 'sendDailyRecap'
                        ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
);
```